# Select a List Slices of a Pandas Multiindex/Multicolumn DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Say I have the following multicolumn Pandas DataFrame:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', ],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', ]]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 6), columns=arrays)

      bar                 baz                 foo          
      one       two       one       two       one       two
0  1.018709  0.295048 -0.735014  1.478292 -0.410116 -0.744684
1  1.388296  0.019284 -1.298793  1.597739  0.044640 -0.040337
2 -0.151763 -0.424984 -1.322985 -0.350483  0.590343 -2.189122
3 -0.221250 -0.449578 -1.512640  0.077380 -0.485380 -0.687565
4 -0.334315  1.790056  0.245414 -0.236784 -0.788226  0.483709
5 -0.943732  1.437968 -0.114556 -1.098798  0.482486 -1.527283
6 -1.213711  1.573547  0.425109  0.513945  0.731550  1.216149
7  0.709976  1.741406 -0.379932 -1.326460 -1.506532 -0.795053
```

What is the syntax to select a combination of multiple slices, like selecting  ('bar',:) and ('baz':'foo','two')?  I know I can do something like:

```
df.loc[:, [('bar', 'one'), ('baz', 'two')]]

        bar       baz
        one       two
0  1.018709  1.478292
1  1.388296  1.597739
2 -0.151763 -0.350483
3 -0.221250  0.077380
4 -0.334315 -0.236784
5 -0.943732 -1.098798
6 -1.213711  0.513945
7  0.709976 -1.326460
```

And something like:

```
print(df.loc[:, ('bar', slice(None))])

        bar          
        one       two
0  1.018709  0.295048
1  1.388296  0.019284
2 -0.151763 -0.424984
3 -0.221250 -0.449578
4 -0.334315  1.790056
5 -0.943732  1.437968
6 -1.213711  1.573547
7  0.709976  1.741406
```

But something like:

```
print(df.loc[:, [('bar', slice(None)), ('baz', 'two')]])
```

Raises a TypeError exception, while

```
print(df.loc[:, ['bar', ('baz', 'two')]])
```

raises a ValueError exception.

So what I am after is a simple syntax to create the following with two slices like:

`[('bar', slice(None)), ('baz', 'two')]`:

```
        bar                 baz
        one       two       two
0 -1.438018  1.511736  0.186499
1 -0.432313 -0.478824 -0.055930
2  0.995103 -0.181832 -0.257952
3  0.972293  2.580807  1.536281
4 -0.496261  1.038807  0.209853
5  0.788222 -1.325234 -1.328570
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to extend [this great answer from @bunji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42891773/5741205) with the [pd.IndexSlice[...]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) method:

```
In [75]: df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[['bar','baz'], 'two']]
Out[75]:
        bar       baz
        two       two
0 -0.037198  0.814649
1  1.272708  1.258576
2  0.405093 -0.243942
3  0.126001  1.751699
4 -0.135793  0.753241
5 -0.433305 -0.192642
6  0.939398  1.356368
7 -0.121508  3.719689
```

another less performative solution - using chained `filter` method:

```
In [78]: df.filter(like='two').filter(regex='(bar|baz)')
Out[78]:
        bar       baz
        two       two
0 -0.037198  0.814649
1  1.272708  1.258576
2  0.405093 -0.243942
3  0.126001  1.751699
4 -0.135793  0.753241
5 -0.433305 -0.192642
6  0.939398  1.356368
7 -0.121508  3.719689
```

Comment: Interesting!  Does this also let you get different columns from different groups though?  For example, if I wanted ('bar','one'), ('bar','two') and ('baz','two').  I've tried different variations on the syntax but can't seem to get it right.  I'll either get exceptions or unexpected results (like in my first comment on bunji's answer)

Comment: @Andrew, try this: `df.loc[:, [('bar','one'), ('baz','two'), ('baz', 'two')]]`

Answer (score 3):

The type error is because you're asking it to look up a list of indices instead of a tuple of indices. Tuples are hashable whereas lists are not so you get an error because it's trying to hash `[('bar', slice(None)), ('baz', 'two')]]`.
Try:

```
print(df.loc[:, (('bar', slice(None)), ('baz', 'two'))])
```

Comment: That works great, except if I change the order.  Not sure why

    print(df.loc[:, (('baz', 'two'), ('bar', slice(None)))])

returns columns ('baz','one') and ('baz','two')

Comment: Did something change in the new pandas (using 1.2.4), or did I not set something up well? When I run the code of OP to generate the dataframe and then the code above I still get TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the multiple slices and build the indices yourself without too much trouble.

**Code:**

```
def combine_slices(frame, *slices):
    return list(sorted(sum([
        list(frame.columns.get_locs(s)) for s in slices], [])))

df[combine_slices(df, ('bar', slice(None)), ('baz', 'two'))]
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', ],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', ]]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), columns=arrays)

print(df[combine_slices(df,
    ('bar', slice(None)),
    ('baz', 'two'),
)])
```

**Results:**

```
        bar                 baz
        one       two       two
0 -1.438018  1.511736  0.186499
1 -0.432313 -0.478824 -0.055930
2  0.995103 -0.181832 -0.257952
3  0.972293  2.580807  1.536281
4 -0.496261  1.038807  0.209853
5  0.788222 -1.325234 -1.328570
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`query` syntax on `pd.MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax)
Only issue is that `query` only works on the index so we'll have to transpose to and from.

```
df.T.query('ilevel_0 in ["bar", "baz"] or ilevel_1 == "two"').T

        bar                 baz                 foo
        one       two       one       two       two
0  0.684387  0.688040 -1.868616 -0.618797 -0.187312
1 -0.111344 -0.633866 -0.245142 -2.673403  0.281421
2 -0.122203 -1.275920 -0.722925 -0.812835 -0.639630
3 -0.512743 -0.273289 -0.733837 -0.091343  1.050064
4  0.867375 -0.442477 -0.342420  1.785535 -0.348037
5  1.148774  0.669942 -0.845356 -1.322135  0.258731
6 -0.707214  1.668921 -0.291904  1.874307  0.152995
7  0.436886  0.102186 -0.720527  0.825798  0.328133
```

Comment: That's interesting. Yesterday i was trying to find something like 'clevel_0' (analog for `ilevel_0` for multi-level columns) in the source code. It would be really helpful in such cases as transposing might be expensive...

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I also cannot reference a multiindex column in a query statement, but could not find any documentation backing up the idea that it's officially unsupported